# Javascript parameters passing

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

This is the code I have been given. I looked around and I don't quite understand.

This is my question function destroyer accepts one parameter an array but when its being called 3 parameters are sent: an array and 2 integers.

How can I access the two integer parameters in the function if they haven't been passed? Is there something in Javascript that would allow this?

```
         function destroyer(arr) {
         // Remove all the value;
         return arr;

        }

        destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `arguments` variable in your function to get a list of passed arguments.

```js
// ES5
function destroyer(arr) {
    var pieces = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 1);
    var i = 0;

    while (arr[i]) {
        -1 === pieces.indexOf(arr[i]) ? i++ : arr.splice(i, 1);
    }

    return arr;
}

// ES6
function destroyer2(arr, ...pieces) {
    var i = 0;

    while (arr[i]) {
        -1 === pieces.indexOf(arr[i]) ? i++ : arr.splice(i, 1);
    }

    return arr;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 3, 1)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(destroyer2([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)));
```

Comment: thank you, really appreciate it .. had me stuck for a while